# Pandas agg function does not calculate the mean after grouping (DataError: No numeric types to aggregate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this df with start and end dates and I would like to calculate the difference between the start and end dates then the mean by customer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'action':['action1','action2','action3','action1','action2','action3','action1','action2','action3'],
                   'start_dt':['2021-10-21 07:48:40','2021-10-27 08:35:13','2021-08-03 03:27:17','2021-08-11 04:16:21','2022-03-04 05:32:12','2021-11-22 07:20:52','2022-02-28 02:37:11','2022-05-31 06:11:13','2022-09-14 01:16:27'],
                   'end_dt':['2021-10-21 07:53:48','2021-10-27 08:35:07','2021-08-03 03:43:01','2021-08-11 10:27:49',pd.NaT,'2021-11-22 07:20:50','2022-02-28 05:48:08','2022-05-31 06:12:08','2022-09-14 13:55:48']})
```

gives:

```
  customer   action             start_dt               end_dt
0         1  action1  2021-10-21 07:48:40  2021-10-21 07:53:48
1         1  action2  2021-10-27 08:35:13  2021-10-27 08:35:07
2         1  action3  2021-08-03 03:27:17  2021-08-03 03:43:01
3         2  action1  2021-08-11 04:16:21  2021-08-11 10:27:49
4         2  action2  2022-03-04 05:32:12                  NaT
5         2  action3  2021-11-22 07:20:52  2021-11-22 07:20:50
6         3  action1  2022-02-28 02:37:11  2022-02-28 05:48:08
7         3  action2  2022-05-31 06:11:13  2022-05-31 06:12:08
8         3  action3  2022-09-14 01:16:27  2022-09-14 13:55:48
```

I made some steps:

```
date_cols = df.filter(like='_dt').columns
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

def datsub(df):
    
    if (df['end_dt'] > df['start_dt']):
        return (df['end_dt'] - df['start_dt'])
    else:
        return pd.NaT
df['diff'] =  df.apply(lambda x: datsub(x), axis=1)
```

Got:

```
   customer   action            start_dt              end_dt     diff
0         1  action1 2021-10-21 07:48:40 2021-10-21 07:53:48 00:05:08
1         1  action2 2021-10-27 08:35:13 2021-10-27 08:35:07      NaT
2         1  action3 2021-08-03 03:27:17 2021-08-03 03:43:01 00:15:44
3         2  action1 2021-08-11 04:16:21 2021-08-11 10:27:49 06:11:28
4         2  action2 2022-03-04 05:32:12                 NaT      NaT
5         2  action3 2021-11-22 07:20:52 2021-11-22 07:20:50      NaT
6         3  action1 2022-02-28 02:37:11 2022-02-28 05:48:08 03:10:57
7         3  action2 2022-05-31 06:11:13 2022-05-31 06:12:08 00:00:55
8         3  action3 2022-09-14 01:16:27 2022-09-14 13:55:48 12:39:21
```

Finally, I want to calculate the mean diff date after group by `customer`:

```
df.groupby('customer').agg({'diff':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

It is strange it works with sum, max ..etc but it does work for **the mean** I do not know why!

I tried to

```
df.fillna(pd.Timedelta('0 days'))
```

Tried also to use `lamdba`:

```
df.groupby('customer').agg({'diff': lambda x: sum(x) / len (x)}).reset_index()
```

But it also does not work!

Comment: It works fine with Pandas 1.4.3

Comment: Yes, I just checked my installed pandas version '1.0.5' which is outdated . It seems that I need to find another solution for that as upgrading pandas is not feasible for me right now!

Comment: Your best bet if you can't upgrade pandas is to improve your lambda approach using a very robust function that handles every possible and always guarantees a return.

Comment: @ticster yes, I am working on that! Thank you

Comment: `def mean_calc(df):
    remove_NAT = df[df['diff'].notnull()]
    return remove_NAT.groupby('customer').agg({'diff':lambda x : x.sum() / len(x)}).reset_index()`

This is the equivalent function for this question future reference. Mean calculation does not consider pd.NaT values so dropping those values from the df and then we calculate the mean.
Thanks everyone